# Flutter icons do not show in app bar but it works in body

Tags: ios, flutter

I am trying to add Icon Button in the leading of App Bar, but the icon do not appear in the app bar.

Below is my reusable AppBarWidget code:

```
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {

  final String appBarTitle;
  final bool backButton;
  final VoidCallback buttonAction;
  CustomAppBar({this.appBarTitle, this.backButton, this.buttonAction});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (backButton) {
      return AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
            appBarTitle,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 20.0,
              fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            )
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          onPressed: buttonAction,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
            appBarTitle,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 20.0,
              fontFamily: 'SF Pro Display',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            )
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```

Below is my ProfilePic.dart that called the app bar:

```
class ProfilePicPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfilePicState createState() =>
      _ProfilePicState();
}

class _ProfilePicState
    extends State< ProfilePicPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: ConstantColor.BackgroundGrey,
        appBar: AppBarSimple(
          appBarTitle: 'profile_picture',
          backButton: true,
          buttonAction: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
```

When i run it in real iPhone device, i got the error below:

[Error Message in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SERO5.png)

But when I tried add the icon in the body, it does appeared in the body.

[The icon shows in body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl9gN.png)

I also have included "uses-material-design: true" in pubspec.yaml.

```
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't see the `leadingIcon` because it's in color white by default which is the same with your `backgroundColor: Colors.white` in AppBar. Try putting a color in your `leadingIcon`. You can't see it but it's there.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing icon color is in white color. I am able to see the leadingIcon by changing the color of the icon.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

`leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),`

Answer (score 0):

I don't what error is, But I can give you alternate way, instead of using IconButton use Icon and wrap it inside Gesture Detector.

```
leading: GestureDetector(
          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          onPressed: buttonAction,
        ),
```

Try doing these

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding Cupertino Icons to the pubspec.yaml. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoIcons-class.html

```
name: my_awesome_application

dependencies:
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm Think, it's might missing a size or a color of the icon. Have you're trying to set the icon size and color?

EX:

```
Icon(
      Icons.arrow_back_ios,
      color: Colors.green,
      size: 30.0,
)
```

Comment: Yes, changing the color of the icon is worked for me. Like MJ Montes said, the icon was in white color, so by changing the color, i am able to see the icon appeared in the button.